# oracle.dataAccess.dll getting an error when connecting via 12c Client

Tags: c#, sql, oracle11g, odp.net, oracle12c

I am working on upgrading oracle database of a installed .Net application from 11g to 12c.

I have upgraded the Oracle client to 12.1.0.2 and pointed the application to new database.

When i was using one of the component i was seeing the error `Error Message: Data provider internal error(-3000) [System.String]`

> Error Stack:    at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32
>   errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx*
>   pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32
>   isRecoverable)    at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode,
>   OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src)    at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()

I have researched internet for possible solution and found that `oracle.dataAccess dll` doesnt work with 12c client and 12c Client need managed dlls uploaded onto the application and require code changes.

But my scope doesn't allow me to update the code, So am looking for a process to connect to 12c oracle client with my application which has `Oracle.dataAccess.dll`, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Downgrade your Oracle client.

Comment: Hi Mike, Does that mean there is no other way to connect using 12C?

Comment: I haven't done the migration myself, but I also don't have the same issue as you, I can recompile against the newer libraries.  Since you need code changes to support the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client, I don't think you have much of a choice by running the older client.  It shouldn't matter in the short term, but you may need to get your vendor to give you a newer build against the 12c client. Oracle has been working hard to get rid of the older stuff,

Comment: You say you  "upgraded the Oracle client" but did you use the installer to install ODP.NET 12.1.0.2? There's tight dependencies between all the DLLs in the stack, so you should do a proper install of ODP.NET. 32 bit: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html

Comment: Thanks for responding to my query,